# Display the names of all .txt documents within the current (or specified) directory

Tags: java, directory

So I have the following code (which has been shamelessly copied from a tutorial so I can get the basics sorted), in which it asks the player to load their game (text-based adventure game)
but I need a way to display all the saved games in the directory. I can get the current directory no worries. Here is my code:

```
public void load(Player p){
        Sleep s = new Sleep();
        long l = 3000;

        Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you wish to load: ");
        String username = i.next();
        File f = new File(username +".txt");
        if(f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("File found! Loading game....");
            try {
                //information to be read and stored
                String name;
                String pet;
                boolean haspet;

                //Read information that's in text file
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                name = reader.readLine();
                pet = reader.readLine();
                haspet = Boolean.parseBoolean(reader.readLine());
                reader.close();

                //Set info
                Player.setUsername(name);
                Player.setPetName(pet);
                Player.setHasPet(haspet);

                //Read the info to player
                System.out.println("Username: "+ p.getUsername());
                s.Delay(l);
                System.out.println("Pet name: "+ p.getPetName());
                s.Delay(l);
                System.out.println("Has a pet: "+ p.isHasPet());

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

```
File currentDirectory = new File(currentDirectoryPath);
File[] saveFiles = currentDirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first get a `File` object for the directory:

```
File ourDir = new File("/foo/bar/baz/qux/");
```

Then by checking `ourDir.isDirectory()` you can make sure you don't accidentally try to work on a file. You can handle this by falling back to another name, or throwing an exception.

Then, you can get an array of `File` objects:

```
File[] dirList = ourDir.listFiles();
```

Now, you may iterate through them using getName() for each and do whatever you need.

For example:

```
ArrayList<String> fileNames=new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dirList.length; i++) {
    String curName=dirList[i].getName();
    if(curName.endsWith(".txt"){
        fileNames.add(curName);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
File folder = new File("path/to/txt/folder");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();
File[] txtFiles = new File[files.length];
int count = 0;

for(File file : files) {
    if(file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".txt")) {
        txtFiles[count] = file;
        count++;
    }
}
```

It should be pretty self explanatory, you just need to know `folder.listFiles()`.

To trim down the `txtFiles[]` array use `Array.copyOf`.

`File[] finalFiles = Array.copyOf(txtFiles, count);`

From the docs:

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with false (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length.

Comment: While valid this may leave a good gap in the array. Perhaps use an arrayList or other composite type instead?

Comment: @hexafraction `count` was meant to be included in the `if` statement, this shouldn't leave any gaps. Thanks for pointing it out, I've edited it now. Edit: Unless you mean nulls after all the values in which case yes an ArrayList would be better, but I guess OP is quite new to Java and he might want to keep in simple in which case a simple array should suffice.

Comment: No, the problem is that txtFiles is being made with a length made to store ALL the files in the folder, while it should only accommodate the txt files themselves.

Comment: @hexafraction Yes, true, I'll alter my answer.